# Closing JavaFX Tab doesn't release memory

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, javafx

I posted a similar question yesterday about releasing memory when removing a Label ([JavaFX GUI doesn't release memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762966/javafx-gui-doesnt-release-memory)). It turned out I was holding on to a reference in an action listener. Today I've been trying to do a similar thing with the `Tab` control, this time there are no listeners I've added since they are built in to the JavaFX control.

When closing a `Tab` the heap still contains the `Tab` instance along with some of it's inner classes. Is there anything I can do to release the memory or is it a bug in JavaFX?

```
public class TabTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab());
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB);

        //create scene and stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is a bug, should be fixed in Java 8u20 (see availability here : http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/releases/8u20.html) : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25652